# Collect Suffixes for all Complete Words below a Trie Node (using recursion in Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I need to add the ability to list suffixes to implement our autocomplete feature. To do that, I implemented a function on the TrieNode object that will return all complete word suffixes that exist below it in the trie. For example, if our Trie contains the words ["fun", "function", "factory"] and we ask for suffixes from the `f` node, we would expect to receive `["un", "unction", "actory"]` back from `node.get_suffixes()`. Here is how I get started:

```
class TrieNode:

    def __init__(self):
        ## Initialize this node in the Trie
        self.word_end = False
        self.children = dict()

    def insert(self, char):
        ## Add a child node in this Trie
        if not char in self.children:
            self.children[char] = TrieNode()

    def get_suffixes(self):
        pass
```

I have tested the `get_suffixes` function separately and it seemed to work fine.

```
result = []
def get_suffixes(node, suffix=""):
    if not node.children == dict():
        for key in node.children:
            suffix += key
            if node.children[key].word_end:
                result.append(suffix)
            get_suffixes(node.children[key], suffix)
            suffix = suffix[:-1]
    return result
```

How is how I tested the function:

```
# Create a mock trie for the test
node = TrieNode()
node.insert("A")
node.children["A"].word_end = True
node.children["A"].insert("t")
node.children["A"].children["t"].word_end = True
node.children["A"].insert("b")
node.children["A"].children["b"].insert("a")
node.children["A"].children["b"].children["a"].insert("c")
node.children["A"].children["b"].children["a"].children["c"].insert("a")
node.children["A"].children["b"].children["a"].children["c"].children["a"].word_end = True
node.children["A"].insert("d")
node.children["A"].children["d"].insert("d")
node.children["A"].children["d"].children["d"].word_end = True
node.children["A"].children["d"].insert("m")
node.children["A"].children["d"].children["m"].insert("i")
node.children["A"].children["d"].children["m"].children["i"].insert("n")
node.children["A"].children["d"].children["m"].children["i"].children["n"].word_end = True

result = []
def get_suffixes(node, suffix=""):
    if not node.children == dict():
        for key in node.children:
            suffix += key
            if node.children[key].word_end:
                result.append(suffix)
            get_suffixes(node.children[key], suffix)
            suffix = suffix[:-1]
    return result

get_suffixes(node.children["A"]) # Returns ['t', 'baca', 'dd', 'dmin'], as expected
```

The problem occured when I tried moving the `get_suffixes` function to the `TrieNode` class. Here I do not know how I should tackle the global variable `result`. It is not supposed to be a global variable anymore. I have tried two versions:

Version I: make `result` a class attribute

```
class TrieNode:

    def __init__(self):
        ## Initialize this node in the Trie
        self.word_end = False
        self.children = dict()
        self.result = []

    def insert(self, char):
        ## Add a child node in this Trie
        if not char in self.children:
            self.children[char] = TrieNode()

    def get_suffixes(self, suffix=""):
        if not self.children == dict():
            for key in self.children:
                suffix += key
                if self.children[key].word_end:
                    self.result.append(suffix)
                self.children[key].get_suffixes(suffix)
                suffix = suffix[:-1]   
        return self.result 

node.children["A"].get_suffixes() # Returns ['t'], which is wrong
```

Version II: make `result` a default function parameter

```
class TrieNode:

    def __init__(self):
        ## Initialize this node in the Trie
        self.word_end = False
        self.children = dict()

    def insert(self, char):
        ## Add a child node in this Trie
        if not char in self.children:
            self.children[char] = TrieNode()

    def suffixes(self, suffix="", result=[]):
        if not self.children == dict():
            for key in self.children:
                suffix += key
                if self.children[key].word_end:
                    result.append(suffix)
                self.children[key].suffixes(suffix)
                suffix = suffix[:-1]   
        return result

node.children["A"].suffixes() # Returns ['t', 'baca', 'dd', 'dmin']
node.children["A"].suffixes() # Returns ['t', 'baca', 'dd', 'dmin', 't', 'baca', 'dd', 'dmin']
```

The result of Version II is not surprising because:

```
def append(number, number_list=[]):
    number_list.append(number)
    print(number_list)
    return number_list

append(5) # expecting: [5], actual: [5]
append(7) # expecting: [7], actual: [5, 7]
append(2) # expecting: [2], actual: [5, 7, 2]
```

I am learning algorithms and data structure in Python. I was asked to do it using a recursive function. Other approaches such as [Implementing a Trie to support autocomplete in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038694/implementing-a-trie-to-support-autocomplete-in-python) are not the answers I expect though they themselves might be able to solve the problem. I am extremely curious why `self.result` is not properly modified in Version I but works properly if it does not reside in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` belongs to the class `TrieNode`.

When you return `self.result` from the `get_suffixes` method, you are only including the answers found in the current `TrieNode` Instance.

You need to include the answers found by its children as well. Thanks to recursion the code just needs a minor change  and adding `self.result+=self.children[key].get_suffixes(suffix)` makes everything work.

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        ## Initialize this node in the Trie
        self.word_end = False
        self.children = dict()
        self.result = []

    def insert(self, char):
        ## Add a child node in this Trie
        if not char in self.children:
            self.children[char] = TrieNode()

    def get_suffixes(self, suffix=""):
        if not self.children == dict():
            for key in self.children:
                suffix += key
                if self.children[key].word_end:
                    self.result.append(suffix)
                else:
                    self.result+=self.children[key].get_suffixes(suffix)
                suffix = suffix[:-1]   
        return self.result 



# Create a mock trie for the test
node = TrieNode()
node.insert("A")
node.children["A"].word_end = True
node.children["A"].insert("t")
node.children["A"].children["t"].word_end = True
node.children["A"].insert("b")
node.children["A"].children["b"].insert("a")
node.children["A"].children["b"].children["a"].insert("c")
node.children["A"].children["b"].children["a"].children["c"].insert("a")
node.children["A"].children["b"].children["a"].children["c"].children["a"].word_end = True
node.children["A"].insert("d")
node.children["A"].children["d"].insert("d")
node.children["A"].children["d"].children["d"].word_end = True
node.children["A"].children["d"].insert("m")
node.children["A"].children["d"].children["m"].insert("i")
node.children["A"].children["d"].children["m"].children["i"].insert("n")
node.children["A"].children["d"].children["m"].children["i"].children["n"].word_end = True


print(node.children["A"].get_suffixes())
```

Output:-

```
['t', 'baca', 'dd', 'dmin']
```

The thing to remember is that every child is a new instance of the `TrieNode` class and thus has its own separate `result` array.

Modified Insertion + No Result Array:-

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        ## Initialize this node in the Trie
        self.word_end = False
        self.children = dict()

    def insert(self, string):
        if len(string) == 0:
            self.word_end = True
            return
        ## Add a child node in this Trie
        if not string[0] in self.children:
            self.children[string[0]] = TrieNode()
        self.children[string[0]].insert(string[1:])

    def get_suffixes(self, suffix=""):
        query_result=[]
        if self.word_end:
            query_result.append(suffix)
        for i in self.children:
            query_result+=self.children[i].get_suffixes(suffix+i)
        return query_result




# Create a mock trie for the test
node = TrieNode()
node.insert("Add")
node.insert("At")
node.insert("Abaca")
node.insert("Admin")

print(node.children["A"].get_suffixes())
print(node.children["A"].get_suffixes())
print(node.children["A"].children["t"].get_suffixes())
```

Output:-

```
['dd', 'dmin', 't', 'baca']
['dd', 'dmin', 't', 'baca']
['']
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: @JamesChang I was wondering if you want the insert function to be that way? A recursive insert with a String instead of characters would be easier.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I see that this is a node of a trie, so what you did is correct as well.

Comment: There's a problem if you use += with result. It seems when you execute get_suffixes() multiple times the list returned keeps accumulating. This is similar to Version II in the question I showed you.

Comment: A fix would be to either clear the result array after each query or use a temporary array to calculate the result to each query. `temp=self.result;
  self.result=[];
  return temp;` I've updated the answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, though this does not look very elegant.

Comment: I agree, answer to a query should not modify the state of a Class Instance. The `result` array is not a characteristic of the TrieNode class, word_end and children make sense because without them we can't define a Trie Node. Maybe removing the `result` array altogether would be better?

Comment: yeah, but if I remove `result` in the class attribute there's no way the global variable `result` can reside.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake in the definition of `get_suffixes` function. It failed to deal with some edge cases. I have updated my question.

Comment: What if the `result` array is dropped altogether and each query result is stored in a variable and used as desired? Check the updated answer once. Tbh, I don't understand the requirement. Do you need a `result` array? If yes, do you need it to be global or as an attribute to the Class? You've already done the latter and included the code in the question. I'm just a little lost here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212520/discussion-between-james-chang-and-asds-asds).